# When using Autowire, where do you set the bean you want wired up?

Tags: java, spring

When you mark something with the Autowire annotation, you are saying you want this particular e.g. class to be automatically wired for DI.

Now where exactly do you set the target class to be used in the Autowire?

reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config

so in this example below, you autowire the setter:

```
public class SimpleMovieLister {

    private MovieFinder movieFinder;

    @Required
    public void setMovieFinder(MovieFinder movieFinder) {
        this.movieFinder = movieFinder;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Will spring just search for any class that implements the interface MovieFinder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will spring just search for any class
>   that implements the interface
>   MovieFinder?

Essentially, yes. It gets interesting when it finds more than one, upon which it will throw an exception on context startup, unless you take steps to help it out.

There are 3 ways to address multiple autowire candidates:

- Mark the ones you *don't* want to autowire with `autowire-candidate="false"`.
- Mark the one you *do* want to autowire with `primary="true"`
- Qualify the `@Autowired` annotation by specifying `@Qualifier("TheBeanIWant")`

Any of the above will work, you pick the one that suits your situation best.

`@Qualifier("TheBeanIWant")` and `@Resource(name="TheBeanIWant")` are rather similar, the difference is that `@Qualifier` is helping Spring narrow down the autowiring, whereas `@Resource` is explicitly picking out a bean by name, regardless of type.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a bean of type `MovieFinder` in the context, it will be injected. If there are more than one beans of that type, an exception will be thrown.

In the case of constructor injection, `@Autowired` (and `@Required` I assume) are only autowire-by-type.

If you want to explicitly specify a name using annotations, use `@Resource(name="beanId")`

Comment: its nice having everything in one place sometimes i.e xml file

Comment: well, no, annotations make perfect sense if you master them.

Comment: I see, well if you have 1+ implementations you said you can specificy the beanId, but then you need to declare the beans in XML or can you set the beanID via annotations?

Comment: you can set the ids via annotations. Also, they have default ids. for example `@Component public class SomeBeanImpl` has the default name `someBeanImpl`